# prob package seems to miscalculate Conditional Probability?

Tags: r, statistics, probability, bayesian

I am using the `prob` package in R to calculate Conditional probability.

My data set is

```
 Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 

  1  1  0  0  
  0  0  0  0  
  0  1  0  1  
  0  1  0  1
```

I want to calculate prob(Q2 =1 given Q4=1), as per my knowledge it should be 1. But when I use following command in R

`Prob(a,Q2==1,Q4==1)` it return 0.5

**How come it return 0.5? Is 0.5, right? I am doubting my answer.**

The second question is If I change the data set to

```
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 
  1  1  0  0 
  1  0  1  0 
  0  1  0  1 
  1  1  1  1
```

When I use the above data and calculate above probability it returns 1. 
**How come probability changes when I am not changing Q2 and Q4.**
My thinking is it should be same 1 in both cases.

**How come it changes just by the change in other parameter Q1 and Q3. I think it should change as P(Q2=1 / Q4=1) is independent of Q1 and Q3.**

Comment: Please update your question to make it reproducible, aka include data and code that we can run in our R terminals to replicate the results you are getting from the prob package.

Comment: I do have 0.25, in probs

Comment: @ Marat: What is the correct answer as per your opinion. This has forced me to doubt me on my answer.

Comment: @user395882,I think that the given condition should reduce the size of the data set, and the probabilities within the reduced set should be renormalized, so the answer should be 1. What bothers me more is that whatever the correct answer is, it should be identical for both data sets in question.

Comment: I can confirm that the results in question are reproducible on my machine (R 3.3.2 2016-10-31, darwin13.4.0, prob_1.0-0)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Prob` uses `intersect` which excludes duplicates. So the calculation it does is `sum(intersect(A, B)$probs)/sum(B$probs)` which is 0.25/0.5=0.5.

If you want the correct calculation, you have to use exclusive probabilities like so (the 3rd line has a probability of 50%):

```
a <-read.table(text="Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
  1  1  0  0
  0  0  0  0
  0  1  0  1",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
a$probs <-c(0.25,0.25,0.5)

Prob(a,event=Q2==1,given=Q4==1)
[1] 1
```

As for your second question, `Prob` is working correctly because `intersect` is not removing duplicates because line 3 and 4 are different.

Comment: I guess that we found a bug in `Prob`. To fix it, one should replace `p <- sum(intersect(A, B)$probs)/sum(B$probs)` by something linke `p <- sum(x$probs[g & r]) / sum(x$probs[g])` in the function source.

Comment: @MaratTalipov In my opinion, not a bug, though maybe they could add functionality or warnings for misspecified sample spaces.

Comment: @Frank, something like an initial test for duplicates? Perhaps you are right.

Comment: @Marat Yeah, though I guess that could be costly if every function did it. The fancy way to deal with it would be to make a "sample space" class that only accepts tables with unique rows. (Dunno, maybe it does this already; I don't use it myself and just glanced at its vignettes.)

Comment: @ Lapointe: Thanks for your reply. If it uses the intersection, so is not it equivalent to calculate the posterior probability? Should I assume that it is calculating posterior probability, not the conditional probability as it is using the intersection.